# Issue Regarding Query in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am problem creating a query applying condition inside the $search stage in the aggregation pipeline. I had also tried all the operators of the $search stage but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain what's going on with more detail? Could you share your queries? Sample documents? Index definition?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing??, you should clearly define everything, this is insufficient data to give you any solutions.